# Computing many quadratic forms in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a collection of square matrices `Sigma1, Sigma2, ...` .  These are stored in a numpy array `Sigma` such that `Sigma[0, :, :] = Sigma1, Sigma[1, :, :] = Sigma2`, etc.

I have a corresponding set of vectors `v1, v2, ...`, stored in a matrix `v` such that `v[0, :] = v1, v[1, :] = v2`, etc.

I am trying to produce a vector a such that a[0] is `v1.T @ Sigma1 @ v1` (a scalar value), a[1] is `v2.T @ Sigma2 @ v2`, etc.

I'm a bit bewildered by the documentation for `einsum` `tensordot` and the like, which seem promising but which I have been unable to coerce into giving me the desired answer.

For example:

```
Sigma = np.empty(4, 3, 3)
for i in range(4):
    Z = np.random.randn(10, 3)
    Sigma[i, :, :] = Z.T @ Z

y = np.random.randn(4, 3)
```

I want a function `foo(Sigma y)` that returns a vector equivalent to

```
bar = np.empty(4)
for i in range 4:
    bar[i] = y[i, :].T @ Sigma[i, :, :] @ y[i, :]
return bar
```

Comment: Unless your matrices are tiny, I see no reason that computing in a single "instruction" would be faster/better than separate products.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: Edited to provide the requested example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
np.einsum('ij,ijk,ik -> i', y, Sigma, y)
```

is what you are looking for.

```py
In [1]: Sigma = np.random.rand(4, 3, 3)

In [2]: y = np.random.rand(4, 3)

In [3]: bar = np.empty(4)
   ...: for i in range(4):
   ...:     bar[i] = y[i, :].T @ Sigma[i, :, :] @ y[i, :]
   ...:

In [4]: bar_einsum = np.einsum('ij,ijk,ik -> i', y, Sigma, y)

In [5]: np.allclose(bar, bar_einsum)
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick!  The little  arrow ("->") was missing from the other einsum solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want (not tested)

```
 y[i, :].T @ Sigma[i, :, :] @ y[i, :]

 np.einsum('ij,ijk,ik',y,Sigma,y)
```

A `matmul` version should be possible, but `einsum` is easier to write

Comment: Close!  This produces a scalar.  I'm expecting a 4-vector.  np.einsum is producing the sum of the vector I'm aiming for.

Comment: In the `einsum` the `i` dimension passes through.  The result will be as large as the first dimension of `y` and `Sigma`.